# How can I convert string to operator?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, converters

I have a lot of string and they include comparison operator. For example = , <= , >= .... I want to use these strings in IF clause. Like this;

For string value is <= ,

IF X 'string1' Y THEN ...

Is there any converter function or different way in PL/SQL? How can I do this ?

Comment: Where are the strings?  In a table?  In an array in code? Is the entire IF part of the string?  Please show exact examples of the strings and how they are intended to be used, along with expected output.

Comment: They are not important. I just wanted to convert string to operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to use a `CASE` [operator](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php)

```
CASE operator
   WHEN '>'  THEN ....
   WHEN '>=' THEN ....
   WHEN '<'  THEN ....
   WHEN '<=' THEN ....
   ELSE ...
END
```

Comment: I want to make a function or converter but that is enough for my task :) Thank you